# SFTP Transfer with Proxy?

Tags: vbscript, winscp

Can the following WinSCP VBScript file be modified to allow proxy connection?

```
'###########################################################################
'# Function: MISC_FTPUpload
'#
'# Description:
'#  Uses the FSO object to FTP a file to a remote server
'#
'# Parameters:
'#    (in) sSite             - The site to FTP to
'#    (in) sUsername        - The username to log in with
'#    (in) sPassword        - The password to log in with
'#    (in) sLocalFile        - The Locally stored file to FTP to the remote server
'#    (in) sRemotePath    - The path to store the file in, on the remote server
'#
'#    (out) - sError - The error output 
'#
'# Return:
'#  True  - File successfully sent
'#  False - File not successfully sent
'###########################################################################

Function MISC_FTPUpload(byVal sSite, byVal sUsername, byVal sPassword, byVal sLocalFile, byVal sRemotePath, byRef sError)
'This script is provided under the Creative Commons license located
'at http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/ . It may not
'be used for commercial purposes with out the expressed written consent
'of NateRice.com

    Const OpenAsDefault = -2
    Const FailIfNotExist = 0
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Dim oFTPScriptFSO
    Dim oFTPScriptShell
    Dim sOriginalWorkingDirectory
    Dim sFTPScript
    Dim sFTPTemp
    Dim bRetCode
    Dim sFTPTempFile
    Dim oFTPScript
    Dim sResults
    Dim sOut
    Dim sCmd

    LOG_Write "MISC_FTPUpload called at: " & Now

    Set oFTPScriptFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFTPScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    sRemotePath = Trim(sRemotePath)
    sLocalFile = Trim(sLocalFile)

    '----------Path Checks---------
    'Here we will check the path, if it contains
    'spaces then we need to add quotes to ensure
    'it parses correctly.
    If InStr(sRemotePath, " ") > 0 Then
        If Left(sRemotePath, 1) <> """" And Right(sRemotePath, 1) <> """" Then
              sRemotePath = """" & sRemotePath & """"
        End If
    End If

    If InStr(sLocalFile, " ") > 0 Then
        If Left(sLocalFile, 1) <> """" And Right(sLocalFile, 1) <> """" Then
              sLocalFile = """" & sLocalFile & """"
        End If
    End If

    'Check to ensure that a remote path was
    'passed. If it's blank then pass a "\"
    If Len(sRemotePath) = 0 Then
        'Please note that no premptive checking of the
        'remote path is done. If it does not exist for some
        'reason, Unexpected results may occur.
        sRemotePath = "\"
    End If

    'Check the local path and file to ensure
    'that either the a file that exists was
    'passed or a wildcard was passed.
    If InStr(sLocalFile, "*") Then
        If InStr(sLocalFile, " ") Then
            sError = "Error: Wildcard uploads do not work if the path contains a space." & vbNewLine & "This is a limitation of the Microsoft FTP client."
              LOG_Write sError
              MISC_FTPUpload = False
              Exit Function
        End If
    ElseIf Len(sLocalFile) = 0 Or Not oFTPScriptFSO.FileExists(sLocalFile) Then
        'nothing to upload
        sError = "Error: File Not Found."
        LOG_Write sError
        MISC_FTPUpload = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    '--------END Path Checks---------

    'build input file for ftp command
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option batch on" & vbCRLF
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option confirm off"& vbCrLf  
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option transfer binary" & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "open sftp://" & sUsername & ":" & sPassword & "@" & sSite & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "cd " & sRemotePath & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "put " & sLocalFile & vbCRLF
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "close" & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "exit" & vbCrLf

    LOG_Write "Script for FTP File: " & vbNewLine & sFTPScript

    sFTPTemp = oFTPScriptShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
    sFTPTempFile = sFTPTemp & "\" & oFTPScriptFSO.GetTempName
    LOG_Write "FTP Input file stored at: " & sFTPTempFile

    'Write the input file for the ftp command
    'to a temporary file.
    Set oFTPScript = oFTPScriptFSO.CreateTextFile(sFTPTempFile, True)
    oFTPScript.WriteLine(sFTPScript)
    oFTPScript.Close
    Set oFTPScript = Nothing  

    sCmd = """C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"" -script=" & sFTPTempFile 
    MISC_RunCmd sCmd, sOut, sError
    LOG_Write sOut

    Wscript.Sleep 1000

    ' Get rid of temp file used for input to sftp
    oFTPScriptFSO.DeleteFile(sFTPTempFile)

    'Check results of transfer.    
    If sError = ""  And InStr(sOut, "binary") >0  And InStr(sOut, "100%") >0 Then
        MISC_FTPUpload = True
    Else
        sError = "Error: " & sError
        LOG_Write sError
        MISC_FTPUpload = False 
    End If

    Set oFTPScriptFSO = Nothing
    Set oFTPScriptShell = Nothing
End Function

'###########################################################################
'# Function: MISC_FTPDownload
'#
'# Description:
'#  Uses the FSO object to FTP a file from a remote server
'#
'# Parameters:
'#    (in) sSite             - The site to FTP from
'#    (in) sUsername        - The username to log in with
'#    (in) sPassword        - The password to log in with
'#    (in) sLocalPath        - The path to store the file in, on the local drive
'#    (in) sLocalPath        - The path to get the file from, on the remote drive
'#    (in) sRemoteFile    - The remotely stored file to FTP to the local drive
'#
'#    (out) - sError - The error output 
'#
'# Return:
'#  True  - File successfully retrieved
'#  False - File not successfully retrieved
'###########################################################################

Function MISC_FTPDownload(byVal sSite, byVal sUsername, byVal sPassword, byVal sLocalPath, byVal sRemotePath, byVal sRemoteFile, byRef sError)
'This script is provided under the Creative Commons license located
'at http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/ . It may not
'be used for commercial purposes with out the expressed written consent
'of NateRice.com

    Const OpenAsDefault = -2
    Const FailIfNotExist = 0
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Dim oFTPScriptFSO
    Dim oFTPScriptShell
    Dim sOriginalWorkingDirectory
    Dim sFTPScript
    Dim sFTPTemp
    Dim sFTPTempFile
    Dim bRetCode
    Dim oFTPScript
    Dim sResults
    Dim sCmd
    Dim sOut

    LOG_Write "MISC_FTPDownload called at: " & Now

    Set oFTPScriptFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFTPScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    sRemotePath = Trim(sRemotePath)
    sLocalPath = Trim(sLocalPath)

    '----------Path Checks---------
    'Here we will check the remote path, if it contains
    'spaces then we need to add quotes to ensure
    'it parses correctly.
    If InStr(sRemotePath, " ") > 0 Then
        If Left(sRemotePath, 1) <> """" And Right(sRemotePath, 1) <> """" Then
            sRemotePath = """" & sRemotePath & """"
        End If
    End If

    'Check to ensure that a remote path was
    'passed. If it's blank then pass a "\"
    If Len(sRemotePath) = 0 Then
        'Please note that no premptive checking of the
        'remote path is done. If it does not exist for some
        'reason. Unexpected results may occur.
        sRemotePath = "\"
    End If

    'If the local path was blank. Pass the current
    'working direcory.
    If Len(sLocalPath) = 0 Then
        sLocalPath = oFTPScriptShell.CurrentDirectory
    End If

    If Not oFTPScriptFSO.FolderExists(sLocalPath) Then
        'destination not found
        sError = "Error: Local Folder Not Found."
        LOG_Write sError
        MISC_FTPDownload = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    sOriginalWorkingDirectory = oFTPScriptShell.CurrentDirectory
    oFTPScriptShell.CurrentDirectory = sLocalPath
    '--------END Path Checks---------

    'build input file for ftp command
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option batch on" & vbCRLF
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option confirm off"& vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option transfer binary" & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "open sftp://" & sUsername & ":" & sPassword & "@" & sSite & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "cd " & sRemotePath & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "get " & sRemoteFile & vbCRLF
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "close" & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "exit" & vbCrLf

    LOG_Write "Script for FTP File: " & vbNewLine & sFTPScript

    sFTPTemp = oFTPScriptShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
    sFTPTempFile = sFTPTemp & "\" & oFTPScriptFSO.GetTempName
    LOG_Write "FTP Input file stored at: " & sFTPTempFile

    'Write the input file for the ftp command
    'to a temporary file.
    Set oFTPScript = oFTPScriptFSO.CreateTextFile(sFTPTempFile, True)
    oFTPScript.WriteLine(sFTPScript)
    oFTPScript.Close
    Set oFTPScript = Nothing  

    sCmd = """C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"" -script=" & sFTPTempFile 
    MISC_RunCmd sCmd, sOut, sError
    LOG_Write sOut

    Wscript.Sleep 1000

    ' Get rid of temp file used for input to sftp
    oFTPScriptFSO.DeleteFile(sFTPTempFile)

    'Check results of transfer.    
    If sError = ""  And InStr(sOut, "binary") >0  And InStr(sOut, "100%") >0 Then
        MISC_FTPDownload = True
    Else
        sError = "Error: " & sError
        LOG_Write sError
        MISC_FTPDownload = False 
    End If

    Set oFTPScriptFSO = Nothing
    Set oFTPScriptShell = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The proxy would have to act as a [Man in the Middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) for this. [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) (the protocol [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) uses for data transfer) was designed to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

On the line, where you add the `open` command:

```
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "open sftp://" & sUsername & ":" & sPassword & "@" & sSite & vbCrLf
```

... add the `-rawsettings` switch followed by the options relevant for your kind of proxy:

For example:

```
sFTPScript = ... & " -rawsettings ProxyMethod=3 ProxyHost=proxy" & vbCrLf
```

For details refer to:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings

Answer (score 0):

To use the proxy, first use the WINSCP GUI to connect specifying the proxy details. This will add the details of proxy in the configuration file (which is in the same directory as winscp.com) and then it should work. You can then pass the path of this configuration file to your execute process task and call the WINSCP.com executable.

Comment: Please complete your last sentence.

Comment: Hi demongolem, thanks for pointing that out. I had posted the answer to same query on a different site and while copying text the last line was not pasted correctly